# Cannot solve hibernate error QuerySyntaxException: designs is not mapped [from designs]

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets, hql

I'm using hibernate for my final project. I have a table called `designs` for store all the details of artworks. In the explore page i need to get all the designs from the database using `hibernate`. So i created a java class called `designModal.java`,

```
public class designModal {

SessionFactory sf;

public designModal() {
    sf = connection.NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

}

public String[] getAllDesigns() {
    String result[] = new String[8];
    try {
        Session ses = sf.openSession();
        Transaction tr = ses.beginTransaction();
        List<Designs> designList = ses.createQuery("from designs").list();
        for (Designs designs : designList) {
            result[0]= designs.getDesignId().toString();
            result[1]= designs.getTitle();
            result[2]= designs.getImage();
            result[3]= designs.getDescription();
            result[4]= designs.getPrice().toString();
            result[5]= designs.getViews().toString();
            result[6]= designs.getLikes().toString();
            result[7]= designs.getDesigners().toString();
        }
        tr.commit();
        ses.flush();
        ses.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(result[0]+""+result[1]+""+result[3]);
    return result;
}

}
```

Then i called this method in my page,

```
<%@page import="modal.designModal"%>
<%
    String result[] = new designModal().getAllDesigns();
    out.print(result.length);
%>
```

but i got an exception : `QuerySyntaxException: designs is not mapped [from designs]`

I followed some SO questions but that not helped. So I created a new web project,but still not solved. What is the wrong here ? Thank you

**Design.hbm.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Oct 11, 2016 1:11:09 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.6.0 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="pojos.Designs" table="designs" catalog="design">
        <id name="designId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="design_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="designers" class="pojos.Designers" fetch="select">
            <column name="designer_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="galleries" class="pojos.Galleries" fetch="select">
            <column name="gallery_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="title" type="string">
            <column name="title" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="image" type="string">
            <column name="image" length="100" />
        </property>
        <property name="description" type="string">
            <column name="description" length="500" />
        </property>
        <property name="price" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="price" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="views" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="views" />
        </property>
        <property name="likes" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="likes" />
        </property>
        <set name="buysRegisters" table="buys_register" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="design_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="pojos.BuysRegister" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Design.java**

```
package pojos;
// Generated Oct 11, 2016 1:11:09 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.6.0


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Designs generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Designs  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer designId;
     private Designers designers;
     private Galleries galleries;
     private String title;
     private String image;
     private String description;
     private Double price;
     private Integer views;
     private Integer likes;
     private Set buysRegisters = new HashSet(0);

    public Designs() {
    }


    public Designs(Designers designers, Galleries galleries) {
        this.designers = designers;
        this.galleries = galleries;
    }
    public Designs(Designers designers, Galleries galleries, String title, String image, String description, Double price, Integer views, Integer likes, Set buysRegisters) {
       this.designers = designers;
       this.galleries = galleries;
       this.title = title;
       this.image = image;
       this.description = description;
       this.price = price;
       this.views = views;
       this.likes = likes;
       this.buysRegisters = buysRegisters;
    }

    public Integer getDesignId() {
        return this.designId;
    }

    public void setDesignId(Integer designId) {
        this.designId = designId;
    }
    public Designers getDesigners() {
        return this.designers;
    }

    public void setDesigners(Designers designers) {
        this.designers = designers;
    }
    public Galleries getGalleries() {
        return this.galleries;
    }

    public void setGalleries(Galleries galleries) {
        this.galleries = galleries;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public Integer getViews() {
        return this.views;
    }

    public void setViews(Integer views) {
        this.views = views;
    }
    public Integer getLikes() {
        return this.likes;
    }

    public void setLikes(Integer likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }
    public Set getBuysRegisters() {
        return this.buysRegisters;
    }

    public void setBuysRegisters(Set buysRegisters) {
        this.buysRegisters = buysRegisters;
    }
}
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
package connection;


public class NewHibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the name of the Java class used to map the designs table? Apparently no class named **designs** has been mapped.

Comment: I think you are asking about util class. I used Netbeans hibernate wizard.

Comment: can you update your question to include the **Design** class.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
List<Designs> designList = ses.createQuery("from designs").list();
```

to:

```
List<Designs> designList = ses.createQuery("from Designs d").list();
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Can you explain your answer please ?

Comment: @Malinda you need to understand the various query options available. Here you are using Hibernate Query Language (HQL). You could also query by criteria (QBC) or query by example (QBE) or using JPA QL.